# Volume of $\{\vec{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n : \langle A\vec{x},\vec{x} \rangle \leq 1\}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $A \in Mat_{n,n}(\mathbb{R})$ be symmetrical and positive definite.

The function $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ is defined as $f(\vec{x}) = \langle A\vec{x},\vec{x} \rangle$.

One has to find the Volume of the the "ellipsoid" described by $f(\vec{x}) \leq 1$. Or in other words, the volume of the folowing set:
$$\{\vec{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n : \langle A\vec{x},\vec{x} \rangle \leq 1\}$$

One can assume we already know the volume of $\omega_n$, the $n$-dimensional Sphere.

I found it on an old analysis paper on and the question seems to be very interesting, but I have no idea on how this exercise can be solved, so your help is greatly appreciated.

**Update**
Looking at the hint from the comment this seems like a good sketch of proving this but I would love if someone could "fill in the blanks" / find the errors.

Since A can be diagonalized $A = B^{-1}PB$ with $P$ being filled with the positive eigenvalues we can rewrite our equation:

$f(\vec{x}) = \langle A\vec{x},\vec{x} \rangle = \langle B^{-1}PB\vec{x},\vec{x} \rangle$

Let's now look at $g(\vec{x}) = \langle P\vec{x},\vec{x} \rangle = \lambda_1x_1^2 + \cdots + \lambda_nx_n^2$

So our set becomes $\{\lambda_1x_1^2 + \cdots + \lambda_nx_n^2 \leq 1\}$

We now use the substitution $v_i = \sqrt{\lambda_i} x_i$ which results in $C = \{v_1^2 + \cdots + v_n ^2 \leq 1\}$ we know that the volume of $C$ is $\omega_n$
Since we have substituted we must use the multidimensional substitution rule:

Since $v_i = \sqrt{\lambda_i} x_i  \implies x_i =  \frac{v_i}{\sqrt{\lambda_i}}$

We can now build the functional matrix of the change in variable:

$$\begin{bmatrix} \frac{\partial x_i}{\partial v_i} & \cdots \\
\cdots \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\lambda_i}} & \cdots \\
\cdots \end{bmatrix}$$
building the determinant of the functional matrix gives me $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\det P}}$

Using the substitution we therefore get $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\det P}}\omega_n$

this however only works for a matrix $P$ which only has positive values on its diagonal?

Thank you for helping.

Comment: Try to represent $\vec{x}$ in the orthonormal basis consisting of the eigenvectors of $A$. This will give you the equation for this body: $\lambda_1x_1^2+\lambda_2x_2^2+\cdots+\lambda_nx_n^2\le 1$.

Comment: Thanks. That seems like a good idea... I will to do that.

Comment: I've done a quick calculation and my result is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\det A}}\omega_n$, having in mind that $\lambda_1\lambda_2\cdots\lambda_n=\det A$, hope you will get to the same value...

Comment: Hmm, I have tried but haven't quite figured it out yet. I have edited the question above with the "new approach" inspired by your idea. Would you mind explaining how did this?

Comment: I don't think your subsitution will work. Try a linear one: $v_i=\sqrt{\lambda_i}x_i, dx_i=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\lambda_i}}dv_i$

Comment: $\rightarrow$ yes of course. that makes more sense.